# How to pass form to Class-based generic views(TodayArchiveView)?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-generic-views, django-1.4

url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
import os.path
from crm.views import *

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^test/$', tView.as_view()),
)
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import TodayArchiveView
from crm.forms import *
from crm.models import *

class tView(TodayArchiveView):
    model = WorkDailyRecord
    context_object_name = 'workDailyRecord'
    date_field = 'date'
    month_format = '%m'
    template_name = "onlyWorkDailyRecord.html"
    form_class = WorkDailyRecordForm ################## ADD
```

tView is generic view....
WorkDailyRecord is defining model in models.py

I want to pass form('WorkDailyRecordForm' class in forms.py) to template(onlyWorkDailyRecord.html)

How??

add

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class WorkDailyRecordForm(forms.Form):
    contents = forms.CharField(label='',
            widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'contents', 'style':'width:764px; height:35px;'}),
            required=False,
        )
    target_user = forms.CharField(label='',
            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'target', 'style':'width:724px'}),
            required=False,
        )
```

onlyWorkDailyRecord.html

```
<form method="post" action="." class="form-inline" id="save-form">
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-mini" id="workDailyRecord-add">작성</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the class based views you need to mention the `form_class`:

```
form_class = WorkDailyRecordForm
```

A simple example:

```
class tView(TodayArchiveView):
    form_class = WorkDailyRecordForm
    template_name = 'onlyWorkDailyRecord.html'
    model = WorkDailyRecord

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        instance = form.save(commit=True)
        return HttpResponse('Done')

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(tView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

For more information read [generic-editing in class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/)

Comment: Have you written the `dispatch` function for your class view?

Comment: Aamir Adnan//Maybe... No. I don't know what should I do?

Comment: I have added a simple example. Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you! BTW, I write '{{ form.as_table }}' in 'onlyWorkDailyRecord.html'. Is this right??

Comment: yes it is right. `form.as_p` or `form.as_table` both should work. or iterate over form fields manually.

Comment: And... Where should call dispatch function?? In template?? views.py?

Comment: I don't know... Where is defining 'form' variables?
Umm.... If I write '{{ formInput.as_table }}' in 'onlyWorkDailyRecord.html', still work??

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with passing form class into a generic, I was able to do it by overriding the get_context_data() function, in case anyone was looking for this as well.

An example from the mozilla documentation:

```
class BookListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Book

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get the context
        context = super(BookListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Create any data and add it to the context
        context['some_data'] = 'This is just some data'
        return context
```

You would pass the form object into a key in the context dictionary.

Can find more information  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Generic_views).